# Implementing an RMI system in Java - no such object in table

Tags: java, rmi, distributed-computing

I am trying to implement a simple RMI system in Java using three pairs of client/servers. The createDrecord is just a test method for now.

Client Code:

```
public class ManagerClient { 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
    System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
    ClinicServerInterface mtlServer = (ClinicServerInterface)Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:2020/mtl");
    ClinicServerInterface lvlServer = (ClinicServerInterface)Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:2021/lvl");
    ClinicServerInterface ddoServer = (ClinicServerInterface)Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:2022/ddo");

    mtlServer.createDRecord("asdf", "asfa", "asda", "as", "asd");

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Server Code:

```
public class ClinicServer implements ClinicServerInterface { 

private int port;
private String location;

public ClinicServer(int port, String location){
    this.port = port;
    this.location = location;
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    int mtlPort = 2020;
    int lvlPort = 2021;
    int ddoPort = 2022;

    try{
        ClinicServer mtlServer = new ClinicServer(mtlPort, "mtl");
        ClinicServer lvlServer = new ClinicServer(lvlPort, "lvl");
        ClinicServer ddoServer = new ClinicServer(ddoPort, "ddo");

        Remote mtlObj = UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(mtlServer,mtlPort);
        Remote lvlObj = UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(lvlServer,lvlPort);
        Remote ddoObj = UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(ddoServer,ddoPort);

        Registry r = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(2020);

        r.bind("mtl", mtlObj);
        r.bind("lvl", lvlObj);
        r.bind("ddo", ddoObj);


        System.out.println("New Server is up and running!");

    }catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void createDRecord(String firstName, String lastName, String address, String phone, String specialization)
        throws RemoteException {
    System.out.println("Create D Record");

}
```

The server runs fine, with the message being displayed, but when I run the client, I get this as an error:

```
java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at assignment1.ManagerClient.main(ManagerClient.java:36)
```

where line 36 is this line in the ManagerClient class:

```
ClinicServerInterface lvlServer = (ClinicServerInterface)Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:2021/lvl");
```

I've read other threads on here with a similar problem but can't seem to figure out how it applies to my code specifically.

Comment: when you start the server , do you get " New Server is up and running " message ?
I mean does the server run correctly ?

Comment: Alright so in the client code, I changed all the ports to 2020 in the Naming.lookup() method and it executes fine. So is the port number in that method argument supposed to be the port of the Registry or the port of the remote server?

Comment: @Moolerian thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 1):

```
int mtlPort = 2020;
int lvlPort = 2021;
int ddoPort = 2022;
```

You don't need different port numbers for different remote objects. You can use 2020 for all of them and the Registry too.

```
Registry r = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(2020);
```

You need to make this variable static. Otherwise it can be garbage-collected, which can lead to garbage-collection of the servers too, which is what causes this problem.

```
 System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
```

You don't need a security manager in the client unless you're using the RMI codebase feature, which isn't mentioned in your question.

```
ClinicServerInterface lvlServer = (ClinicServerInterface)Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:2021/lvl");
```

This will get a `java.rmi.ConnectException`, as the port number isn't 2020.

Answer (score -1):

I changed all the ports to 2020 in the Naming.lookup() method and it executes fine. I thought this method took the server port number as an argument, not the Registry port number.

Comment: That would not by itself solve a `NoSuchObjectException`.

Comment: It still worked using different ports in the server class, but thanks for the feedback, I changed all the ports to 2020. So as long as all the classes are in the same executable, they can share the same port?

Comment: So long as they are all exported by the same JVM process and there are no socket factories, or equal socket factories.